# how to combine the data from different image modalities like FLAIR, T2,T1 images into one image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, medical

I tried the following code to read images and which of the following method  is correct

```
FLAIR=imread('patient2_FLAIR.png');
T1=imread('patient2_T1.png');
T2=imread('patient2_T2.png');
```

Method 1

```
I=[FLAIR T1 T2]
```

Method 2

```
I=FLAIR+T1+T2
```

2.Do I need to apply intensity correction algorithm separately on these images and then combine

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the purpose of combining these images? They carry different types of information, and therefore are normally analyzed separately.

Comment: In a paper they are combining these to get accurate result

Comment: Well then you should carefully read that paper and figure out how they do it.:-)

Comment: they didnt mention about the implementation

Comment: Well, I'm sorry but then your question cannot be answered. There is to the best of my knowledge no general way to "combine" MR images from different modalities. If that's a regular well written scientific paper, then the authors *must have* either explained how to do this combination themselves, or referred to some other publication that contains the explanation. Are you a master or PhD student? Then talk to your supervisor! Best of luck!